# Iframe height adjustment using javascript

Tags: javascript, c#-4.0, iframe, height

I have an iframe in aspx page:

```
<iframe style="width: 100%;" src="" scrolling="auto" id="reportFrame" runat="server">
                                            </iframe>
```

And JavaScript I am using is below"

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
function getElement(aID) {
    return (document.getElementById) ? document.getElementById(aID) : document.all[aID];
}

function getIFrameDocument(aID) {
    var rv = null;
    var frame = getElement(aID); 
    // if contentDocument exists, W3C compliant(e.g.Mozilla)
    if (frame.contentDocument)
        rv = frame.contentDocument;
    else // bad Internet Explorer  ;)
        rv = document.frames[aID].document;
    return rv;
}

function adjustMyFrameHeight() {
    var frame = getElement("reportFrame");
    var frameDoc = getIFrameDocument("reportFrame");
    alert(frameDoc);
    frame.height = frameDoc.body.offsetHeight + 15;
        }

</script>
```

But I have a case for the src in my .cs page as we retrieve src from query string so the code is:

```
  case "Case1":
                reportFrame.Attributes["src"] = "acd.aspx";
                reportFrame.Attributes["height"] = "355px"; //giving iframe height as script now working.
```

In page load:

```
 this.reportFrame.Attributes.Add("onload", "adjustMyFrameHeight();");
```

I have specified the script in the page load as well as since we are using runat="server" but still script is now working.
Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got an answer after debugging the script step by step that in order to get the Id of the frame, I must specify the whole or complete Id as it was inherited in a Content placeholder of the Master page so whole Id had to be given.